# Фильтр для выборки в ORM, сократить похожие записи?

Tags: orm, kohana, php

Ситуация такая, есть таблица:

```
|id|name|surname|
| 1|Alex|       |
| 2|Max |       |
| 3|Jon |       |
| 4|Alex|       |
```

Как сделать выборку имен так, чтобы идентичные данные как `Alex` не повторялись?

```
$names = ORM::factory('user')->group_by('name')->find_all();
```

Все, сам понял.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` GROUP BY `name`
```

Comment: да, спасибо, до самого дошло.

Answer (score 2):

Странная задача для `ORM`, использовали бы `QueryBuilder` и `distinct()`.
Но если сильно хочется, то:

```
..->group_by('name')
```